# can somebody explain me how inheritance works in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

can somebody please explain me How Inheritance works in javascript (JS), 
i have gone through many Tutorials, but I'm not able to understand what it is achieving.. 
even after night and day no result..

***what i have gone through is :***

```
console.log('Initialized..')

function Animal() {
    this.species = "animal";
}

Animal.prototype.category = function (){
    alert(this.species);
}

function Dog(){
    this.Animal();
}

copyPrototype(Dog, Animal)
var d = new Dog();
d.category();
```

**Referenced Tutorial from http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-inheritance/**

Comment: I'd find a different tutorial. Before that, you should ask yourself whether you really want to do this type of pseudo-classic class-like inheritance, and why.

Comment: hi, Thanks, as im new to js, and i'm from designing backgroud.. im trying to learn how OOPs works.

Comment: @torazaburo There is no reason why any one should not learn any kind of pattern in Javascript. Whether he should use it or not matters though.

Comment: hi @Icebox, I agree and disagree. There is no reason why any one should not learn it, but there may be reasons to focus on other things first, rather than wrestling with how to do Java-like class hierarchies. If he is learning a framework, most offer their own class machinery (which is not to say at some point he should not learn what's going on under the hood). He can also use classes in CoffeeScript, or TypeScript, or ES6/Traceur, without having to worry about arcane details like how to patch up the constructor property of derived classes to make sure `instanceof` works properly or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this: http://www.letscodejavascript.com/v3/episodes/lessons_learned/12 is the best resource on understanding the mechanics we abuse when trying to get classical OOP working in JavaScript.

The following is what I do when someone tells me I *must* use OOP in JS. It's probably something I've picked up online somewhere. Anyways, here goes:

```
/// Make this script available somewhere
var extendsClass = this.extendsClass || function (d, b) {
    function __inheritedProto() { this.constructor = d; }
    __inheritedProto.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __inheritedProto();
}

var Animal = (function() {
    function Animal(data) {
        this.value = data;
    }
    Animal.prototype.method = function() {
        return this.value;
    };
    return Animal;
})();

var Dog = (function(_super) {
    extendsClass(Dog, _super);
    function Dog() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Dog.prototype.method2 = function() {
        return this.value * 2; //do something else
    };
    return Dog;
})(Animal);

/// Create some instances
var animal = new Animal(1);
var dog = new Dog(2);


/// Call some methods
animal.method();  // 1
dog.method(); // 2
dog.method2();// 4
```